# Checking if switch is checked and doing something with the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I optimize this code?

```
for(var i = 0; i<people_to_save_parse.length;i++)
{
                if($(".ID-"+people[i].tdid).is(':checked')==true)
                {
                    people_to_save_parse[i].id = $(".ID-text-"+people[i].tdid).text();
                }else{
                    people_to_save_parse[i].id = "";
                }
                if($(".Name-"+people[i].tdid).is(':checked')==true)
                {
                    people_to_save_parse[i].firstname = $(".Name-text-"+people[i].tdid).text();
                }else{
                    people_to_save_parse[i].firstname = "";
                }
                if($(".Surname-"+people[i].tdid).is(':checked')==true)
                {
                    people_to_save_parse[i].lastname = $(".Surname-text-"+people[i].tdid).text();
                }else{
                    people_to_save_parse[i].lastname = "";
                }
}
```

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: Check if switch is checked and do with some data something

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your question just came up in the ['First Post Review Queue'](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/first-post-review-queue-what-is-it). Your question would be significantly better if you could add some more information about what it does. Also, what do you mean by optimize? Make it go faster, or make it more readable, smaller, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

With a function:

```
var checkedValue = function (tdid, field) {
    if ($("." + field + "-" + tdid).is(':checked')) {
        return $("." + field + "-text-" + tdid).text();
    }
    return "";
}
```

and you could then simply call that with:

```
for(var i = 0; i < people_to_save_parse.length; i++) {
    people_to_save_parse[i].id = checkedValue(people[i].tdid, "ID");
    people_to_save_parse[i].firstname = checkedValue(people[i].tdid, "Name");
    people_to_save_parse[i].lastname = checkedValue(people[i].tdid, "Surname");
}
```

This removes much of the code duplication.

Note also that convention puts the `{` at the end of the line in JavaScript, not at the start of the next line. Also, you should add space between your operators and expressions to make them more readable. Finally, you don't need to add the `== true` as it is not useful in the `if` condition since the `is(":checked")` function returns a boolean already.

A concern I have is that you have two arrays, `people_to_save_parse` and `people`. You index them both with the same `i` index, and there is no apparent control that ensures they are 'in sync'. Are they a 1-to-1 matching pair of arrays?